# How to add shadow to custom marker?

Tags: javascript, google-maps

I'm using the new functionality of Animation (bouncing) found in Google Maps JavaScript API v3.

http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/overlays.html#MarkerAnimations

In the examples in the linked code above, the default map marker icons have a dropshadow show on the map during the bounce.

I'm using a custom map marker icon that is a PNG.

**Question**: How do I create a dropshadow for my custom map marker icon that will also be shown when doing the Animation (bounce) effect?

---

*UPDATE*

---

Here is an example using the default map marker icon.

```
http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/marker-animations-iteration.html
```

How do I do this using a custom map marker icon that also has a drop shadow.

Answer (score -1):

Got it to work.

http://jsfiddle.net/brWhw/

Answer (score -1):

you can use some kind of a shadow maker online, like:

http://www.cycloloco.com/shadowmaker/shadowmaker.htm

Comment: Note to future visitors: this link is dead.As per the Google Maps docs: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/markers#complex_icons "**Note:** Marker shadows were removed in version 3.14 of the Google Maps JavaScript API. Any shadows specified programmatically will be ignored."